# Cast/Convert plain text to RTF in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rtf

I'm looking for a way to simply convert/cast plain text to RTF in my T-SQL INSERT statement.
I'm working from excel where I generated a bunch of INSERT statements. Problem is that the tool reading from the DB requires that the text be in RTF format.

Can this be done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
DECLARE @RTFHeader VARCHAR(55)
DECLARE @RTFFooter VARCHAR(50)
SET @RTFHeader = '{\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss Helvetica;}\f0\pard '
SET @RTFFooter = '\par}'
SELECT @RTFHeader + 'This is your plain text.' + @RTFFooter
```

Save the resulting text as a .RTF file